# Access Column values to Header

Tags: sql

I have a table, "Sort_age" in a file called "Info".

And what i currently have in "Sort_age" is as below:

```
year    month   code    Category    Field   Info
2013    jan      3      student     Name    John
2013    jan      3      student     Age      14
2013    feb      2      teacher     Name    Mika
2013    feb      2      teacher     Age      25
```

However, i would like my output to be as such:

```
year    month   code    Category    Name    Age
2013    jan      3      student     John    14
2013    feb      2      teacher     Mika    25
```

May I know how do i go about doing it in microsoft ACCESS, SQL query?

Thank you!!

Comment: may i know what u have tried for this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b808f/5)

**MS SQL Server 2008 Schema Setup**:

```
Create table Sort_age
(year nvarchar(50),month nvarchar(50),code int,Category  nvarchar(50),Field  nvarchar(50),Info nvarchar(50))

insert into Sort_age
(year ,month ,code,Category,Field,Info)
Values

('2013','jan',3,'student','Name','John'),
('2013','jan',3,'student','Age','14'),
('2013','feb',2,'teacher','Name','Mika'),
('2013','feb',2,'teacher','Age','25')
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT YEAR,MONTH,CODE,CATEGORY,NAME=MAX(INFO) , AGE =MIN(INFO)
FROM Sort_age 
GROUP BY YEAR,MONTH,CODE,CATEGORY 
ORDER BY CODE DESC
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b808f/5/0)**:

```
| YEAR | MONTH | CODE | CATEGORY | NAME | AGE |
|------|-------|------|----------|------|-----|
| 2013 |   jan |    3 |  student | John |  14 |
| 2013 |   feb |    2 |  teacher | Mika |  25 |
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is sql server use this

```
SELECT YEAR,MONTH,CODE,CATEGORY,NAME=MAX(INFO) , AGE =MIN(INFO)
FROM Table 
GROUP BY YEAR,MONTH,CODE,CATEGORY 
ORDER BY CODE DESC
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!!! But can we have more than 2 Max cases? For instance, besides student and teacher, i need 2 more fields namely "phone number" and "classroom " . Ive tried it out and has received a syntax error ): @azar

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT year,Month,Code,Category,
       MAX(CASE WHEN Field = 'Name' THEN Info ELSE null END) AS Name,
       Max(CASE WHEN Field = 'Age' THEN Info ELSE null END) AS Age
FROM Sort_age
GROUP BY year,Month,Code,Category
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b808f/22)**

---

Output would be

```
| YEAR | MONTH | CODE | CATEGORY | NAME | AGE |
|------|-------|------|----------|------|-----|
| 2013 |   jan |    3 |  student | John |  14 |
| 2013 |   feb |    2 |  teacher | Mika |  25 |
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!!! But can we have more than 2 Max cases? For instance, besides student and teacher, i need 2 more fields namely "phone number" and "classroom " . Ive tried it out and has received a syntax error ): @VigneshKumar